# Cannot exchange Auth key for Tokens: invalid_grant error

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am struggling with a problem exchanging Google's authentication key (for Offline access) with Access/Refresh tokens.

When I call the API to get the tokens, I always receive the "invalid_grant" error.

[image: request error]

I can provide the source code of the OAuth page (from where I take that code):

https://pastebin.com/uAS86bj9

```
gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: apiKey,
        clientId: clientId,
        scope: scopes
    })
.....
var user =  data.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();

user.grantOfflineAccess({
        }).then(function (resp) {
              $('#content').append('<br>code: ' + resp.code);   // <-- this is the code
        });
```

and (with a lot more experiments and a lot of strange things):
https://pastebin.com/JDhf88qd

I already tried to:
- use a redirect_uri
- sync time with NTP
- double check clientid and clientsecret

**A better explanation:**

I have my own application with the classic "login with google" (that works perfectly). Now I need the authorization key to impersonate the user from a server application (to download Fitness data).
So I tried two things, both with the same result:

```
user.grantOfflineAccess
```

The promise actually returns me the authorization code.

The second things I tried is to call:

```
var link = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri={url}&response_type=code&client_id='+ clientId +'&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffitness.body.read&access_type=offline';
        window.open(link);
```

and taking the code I receive back from that redirect.

I now need (in my server application) to get the access_token and refresh_token from google servers. I am only simulating this with postman, I will do the requests with some other tool.

So I now try to call

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

or

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

with this data:

```
code={thecode}&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri={url}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

but I receive "invalid_grant" error

Comment: Invalid grant what?  There is a message attached to this.   This might help https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/   Why are you trying to do it manually and not just using authorization in postman?  For that matter how do you intend to guess the redirect uri in postman?

Comment: your question is a bit confusing. Your sample code is client/browser code. Browsers can't request offline access and the `response_type=token`, not `code`. If you are in a browser, you are *not* doing 3-legged auth. OAuth can be used in a wide range of configurations which tends to confuse beginners. Could you explain a little more about your use case.

Comment: @DaImTo Postman is just to test the request; i could use CURL to do that. I only want the JSON answer with the access/refresh tokens, as in your link is done calling "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

Comment: @pinoyyid I tried explaining it better; is it more clear?

Comment: I'm still confused. You post `var link = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri={url}&response_type=code&client_id='+ clientId +'&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffitness.body.read&access_type=offline';
        window.open(link);` which is browser code, but you also say "I now need (in my server application) to get the access_token and refresh_token". Which is it - browser or server?

Comment: That's the link to present the authorization screen to the customer; from that I receive the AuthCode as GET parameter to the redirect uri